# generate browser window screenshot

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have to work with multiple pages (tabs) at once and need to see how the different pages look like at any one instance. Is it possible to take screen shots of open tab in Firefox/Chrome via Javascript?

Comment: Javascript generally has no direct access to the local machine, other than to store cookies.  What concessions would you be willing to make to make this possible?  What environment are you using here?  Could you trigger the screenshots externally as part of automated tests that control the browsers?  Are you doing this all manually (ugh)?  Need more info.

Comment: lets say i am working on a browser extension. can this be done without involving too much complex code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Chrome, use the Aviary **extension**: if you require programmatic access, you could fork from the said extension to provide an API.

There is also the `captureVisibleTab` **[tabs function](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html)** available through Chrome extension: it does all the work (almost ;-) for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to do it programmatically with WebKit you could use:

http://www.phantomjs.org

Here is how it works:

PhantomJS is a command-line tool that packs and embeds WebKit. Literally it acts like any other WebKit-based web browser, except that nothing gets displayed to the screen (thus, the term headless). In addition to that, PhantomJS can be controlled or scripted using its JavaScript API.

Here is an example:

```
$>./panthomjs.exe rasterize.js http://www.google.com google.png
```